# How to position the text in div such that it doesnt affect inner div's

Tags: jquery, html, css

The scenario is similar to this:

```html
<div class="a">
    hello this is my text
    <div class="x">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to display div x exactly on div a.
The problem I'm facing is when I include text, div is positioned in next line.

How do I do this?

Comment: What positioning have you tried? Do you have CSS you can post?

Comment: Wait, why using a block element as a DIV and not an inline element as SPAN? What about pseudo element as `:after`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display a div "over" another div you need to use position:relative to the parent (.a) and position absolute to child (.x)

http://jsfiddle.net/fkowdadt/

```
.a .x {
   position:absolute;
   background:#e74c3c;
   opacity:.5;
   left:0; top:0; bottom:0; right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below code will give you your desired output:

```css
.a{
  position:relative;
 }
.x{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    hello this is my text
    <div class="x">
      akejfhlaqfhe
    </div>
</div>
```